# Hibernate and PostgreSQL - sequence start with -46

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate Framework and PostgreSQL database in my Spring Web application. I have for example sequence named agent_id_seq and at the beggining I alter this sequence by

```
alter sequence agent_id_seq
minvalue 1
start with 1;
```

I am adding records using Hibernate and everything works fine until I remove record using Hibernate and add another record using Hibernate. It makes my sequence start with -46 value! How to fix this?

My Agent model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agent")
public class Agent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "agent_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "agent_seq_gen", sequenceName = "agent_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a sequence from PostgreSQL, not Hibernate, it's created with an `INCREMENT` of 1. But Hibernate blindly assumes all sequences have an `INCREMENT` of 50 unless told otherwise.

So when it gets the value 1 as a result, it assumes that's the last value in the usable range of generated keys`(2-49) .. 2`.

To fix it, specify an explicit increment on your mapping, or `ALTER` the increment on the PostgreSQL sequence to `50`.

I consider this a serious Hibernate bug, personally.

Comment: How do you explicitly tell hibernate the increments?

Comment: @Dragas Last worked on this 5 years ago but IIRC see the `allocationSize` parameter. This topic is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745751/hibernate-sequencegenerator-and-allocationsize . Someone there mentions `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true`