# Hibernate not getting increment correctly from database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

Trying to run my Spring Boot application but Hibernate has the wrong increment: **The increment size of the [exercise_id_seq] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1]**
I used Flyway migration to create my entities.

```
create sequence exercise_id_seq start with 1 increment 1;

create table exercise
(
    id              bigint        not null primary key,
    content         varchar(1000) not null,
    content_latex   varchar(1000) not null,
    exercise_type   varchar(1000) not null,
    solution_latex  varchar(1000),
    solution_number decimal(10, 2),
    points          integer,
    test_only       boolean,
    instructions    varchar(3000),
    created         timestamp     NOT NULL,
    modified        timestamp     NOT NULL,
    creator         varchar(255)  NOT NULL,
    modifier        varchar(255)  NOT NULL
);
```

And have my entity as:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "exercise")
public class Exercise extends EntityBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "exercise_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1,sequenceName = "exercise_id_seq", name = "exercise_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    private String content;
    private String contentLatex;
    private String exerciseType;
    private String solutionLatex;
    private BigDecimal solutionNumber;
    private Long points;
    private Boolean testOnly;
    private String instructions;
}
```

Stacktrace:

````
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.lambda$new$1(SessionFactoryImpl.java:306) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1779) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:305) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [exercise_id_seq] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.configure(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]```

Any ideas?
````

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL database

Comment: potentially see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745751/hibernate-sequencegenerator-and-allocationsize. It mentioned a Hibernate flag that can be set.